# Can one conjugate and use 'suicide' as a verb?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, conjunctions

I don't remember ever seeing suicide used as a standalone verb. I've always seen it as commits suicide or committed suicide.

Can you conjugate and use suicide by itself?

Comment: It's not used much as a verb, but it's certainly legit. See cornbread's post below.

Comment: related: [Difference between “commit suicide” and “suicide”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31604/difference-between-commit-suicide-and-suicide)

Comment: It is a newer verbing of a noun, and so sounds a bit strange. I doubt it is allowed in the New York Times, but more informal writing seems to use it. So you -can- use it, but 'commit suicide' is preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OED has citations for the verb *suicide* meaning ‘to commit suicide’ from 1841 to 1898, and there are citations in the sense ‘to do to death’ from 1876 to 1900. There are two twentieth century citations for the derived adjective *suicided*.

[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/suicide) has an entry for the verb and gives as an example of it use ‘she suicided herself in a very ugly manner’.

Comment: On the other side of the pond, [COHA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coha/) has five cites for *suicided* from 1899 to 1976, while [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) has eight more from 1991 to 2010. COHA also has three cites for *suiciding*, all from the same 1952 source.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suicide?show=2&t=1342104209) states:

> ### suicide
>
> *verb* sui·cid·ed | sui·cid·ing
>
> intransitive verb : to commit suicide

- Sarah suicided on the bleakest of Washington winter mornings.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/suicide), *suicide* is also a verb:

> ***suicide***
>
> **verb (used without object)**
>
> to commit suicide, to kill (oneself).

Answer (score 1):

Sure.
My favorite verb conjugation for the word is, "so and so was suicided"

A murder made to look like a suicide.

Comment: Can you provide any source for this?  I've never seen suicide used in this way for this purpose.